# Trimming characters from a column

Tags: sql

I have a column like this

DATE

"112113"

"011414"

and so on..

I want to remove the first and last characters from the entire DATE column. ie) I want to get rid of these "".

Please help.

Comment: What is your RDBS? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: Do you want to update the column or just remove the quotes when querying the data?

Comment: Can you not just use `REPLACE`?

Comment: @D Stanley I want to remove it from the entire colum. I need an update statement using Replace.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `SUBSTRING` that is if you using TSQL.

```
 SUBSTRING(date, 2, LEN(date) - 2)
```

update: Had parenthesis in the wrong spot

Comment: Shouldn't it be : SUBSTRING(DATE, 2, LEN(date) - 2) ?

Comment: No because `LEN` will return entire string length and you are trying to remove first character and last thus you need to subtract two

Comment: Yeah, but you want to subtract 2 from the result of LEN(Date) not subtract 2 from the column Date

Comment: Yep you are right had my parenthesis in the wrong spot. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are only removing the quotes, you might get away with `REPLACE()` which compatible with most relational database systems.

```
SELECT REPLACE(date, '"', '') FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Will this update my entire column?? If yes, this is what I want. Pls clarify.

Comment: Yes, you could use it in an `UPDATE` statement. I provided a `SELECT` as an example of the function.

Comment: Is this how it goes?  Update tablename
Set [DATE] = Replace(DATE, '"', '') from tablename. I am a newbie in sql..please dont mind if i ask silly questions.

Comment: That looks correct. I'd test with the `SELECT` statement first and create a backup. Probably wouldn't hurt to put `DATE` in brackets throughout. I'd also encourage you to adopt the habit of writing SQL syntax in uppercase and avoiding reserved words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Date, 2,  LEN(Date) - 2) FROM TableName
```

You could then update the Date column as follows:

```
UPDATE TableName
    SET Date = SUBSTRING(Date, 2,  LEN(Date) - 2)
```

Comment: What should OP do after the `SELECT`? How would he / she update the data?

Answer (score 0):

you can do in oracle  as answer below

```
TRIM(BOTH CHR(34) FROM '"011414"')
```

Result: 011414

or you can use `replace("011414",'"');`

or you can use `SUBSTRING` function also.

as per your requirement..